# Get instance of rendered class Button (inside Xamarin.Forms) inside custom button renderer (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the simple custom button in my code:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public bool State { get; set; } = false;
}
```

and its renderer:

```
public class CustomButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
{
    public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var button = (Control as Android.Widget.Button);
            (Control as Android.Widget.Button).Touch += Control_Touch;

            // this don't works:
            if (Control.State) Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray);                
        }
    }
 }
```

And I want to get access to `State` property of `CustomButton` instance inside my `CustomButtonRenderer` class. But I can't, because the `Control` has type `Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatButton`, absolutly unrelated to my `CustomButton` class.

Are there any ways to gain access to fields of rendered `CustomButton` object inside its renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Control` is the native control rendering your `CustomButton`. What you are looking for is the property `Element`, which represents your Xamarin.Forms `CustomButton`.

Within `OnElementChanged` it is available as `e.NewElement`.

```cs
if (e.NewElement is CustomButton customButton 
    && customButton.State) 
{
    Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray);  
}
```